# Conky showing up in Unity Launcher

Tags: 12.04, unity, launcher, conky

I've had my Conky configuration properly working in Ubuntu 12.04 for sometime. After a recent update and reboot Conky is showing up on the Unity Launcher as an entry when it is running. It's not locked to the Launcher. When Conky is killed it goes away.
Nothing has changed in my Conky configuration and otherwise it is working properly. I'm just looking for it to be blacklisted from the Launcher while running.

In the screenshot you can see the Conky entry third from the bottom.

[image]

Comment: Can you post the screenshot

Answer (score 4):

Had that problem yesterday. What I did was change my `.conkyrc` file.

In window specifications:

```
own_window_type normal to own_window_type desktop
```

And everything worked. Hope you fix yours.

Comment: Changing own_window_type to desktop does make the entry on the Launcher go away, but when I click on the desktop with conky running it closes/crashes.

Comment: you'll have to change ccsm. 

In general options, unmark the raise_on_click option.

but i didn't like that so i ditched conky for now =/

Comment: Updating that issue. This whole problem is because unity-webapps. Maybe it mess with X or something.When i remove the feature conky backed up to normal.

Comment: I've come to the same conclusion, Marcos. It is definitely related the the webapps preview ppa. I'm just putting up with it for now.